# Why can't I print ("puts") in heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, console, heroku, logging

I have a Rails app deployed to heroku and need to munge some data in `heroku console`.  To help me do this I've created `cmd.rb` in my lib directory with some methods in it.  Here's what it looks like:

```
class Cmd
  def self.hello
    puts "Hello World"
  end

  def self.create_member
    # real code with multiple "puts" statements here
  end
end
```

And here's what I get when I try to run this in heroku console:

```
$ heroku console
Ruby console for myapp.heroku.com
>> puts User.count
515
=> nil
>> 3.times {|i| puts i}
0
1
2
=> 3
>> require "#{Rails.root}/lib/cmd"
=> true
>> Cmd
=> Cmd
>> Cmd.hello
=> nil
```

There's a notable lack of "Hello World" in the above.  Now I can see the output if I do this in another terminal window:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

But there's a lot of noise in that output, and I'd like to be able to see things incrementally.

Comment: I notice I get a bit less log output if I do `heroku logs --tail --ps web.1`, though it's still pretty noisy.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because of the way Heroku implemented the console:

> On Bamboo, heroku rake and heroku console were implemented as special-cased execution paths, with output delivered over HTTP. This approach has a number of weaknesses, such as timeouts and non-interactivity on rake tasks.

So, one solution might be to upgrade to Cedar: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar

Another solution could be to disable the `rails_log_stdout` functionality. I didn't figure out how to do that, but opening a ticket may get a solution.

Also, you may be able to filter the log results. See 'Filtering': http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Rails.logger instead of the method 'puts'.

Comment: I tried `Rails.logger` -- same result.  `puts` essentially goes to the same place as `Rails.logger`.